# How to create a shared object that is statically linked with pthreads and libstdc++ on Linux/gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, pthreads, libstdc++

How to create a shared object that is statically linked with pthreads and libstdc++ on Linux/gcc?

Comment: Have you tried passing -static and -fPIC to g++ while compiling?

Answer (score 8):

Before I go to answering your question as it was described, I will note that it is not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve in the end, and there is probably a better solution to your problem.

That said - there are two main problems with trying to do what you described:

1. One is, that you will need to decompose `libpthread` and `libstdc++` to the object files they are made with.  This is because *ELF binaries* (used on Linux) have two levels of "run time" library loading - even when an executable is statically linked, the loader has to load the statically linked libraries within the binary on execution, and map the right memory addresses.  This is done before the shared linkage of libraries that are dynamically loaded (shared objects) and mapped to shared memory.  Thus, a shared object cannot be statically linked with such libraries, as at the time the object is loaded, all static linked libraries were loaded already.  This is one difference between linking with a static library and a plain object file - a static library is not merely glued like any object file into the executable, but still contains separate tables which are referred to on loading.  *(I believe that this is in contrast to the much simpler static libraries in MS-DOS and classic Windows, `.LIB` files, but there may be more to those than I remember)*.

   Of course you do not actually have to decompose `libpthread` and `libstdc++`, you can just use the object files generated when building them.  Collecting them may be a bit difficult though (look for the objects referred to by the final Makefile rule of those libraries).  And you would have to use `ld` directly and not `gcc`/`g++` to link, to avoid linking with the dynamic versions as well.
2. The second problem is consequential.  If you do the above, you will sure have such a shared object / dynamic library as you asked to build.  However, it will not be very useful, as once you try to link a regular executable that uses those `libpthread`/`libstdc++` (the latter being any C++ program) with this shared object, it will fail with symbol conflicts - the symbols of the static `libpthread`/`libstdc++` objects you linked your shared object against will clash with the symbols from the standard `libpthread`/`libstdc++` used by that executable, no matter if it is dynamically or statically linked with the standard libraries.

   You could of course then try to either hide all symbols in the static objects from `libstdc++`/`libpthread` used by your shared library, make them private in some way, or rename them automatically on linkage so that there will be no conflict.  However, even if you get that to work, you will find some undesireable results in runtime, since both `libstdc++`/`libpthread` keep quite a bit of state in global variables and structures, which you would now have duplicate and each unaware of the other.  This will lead to inconsistencies between these global data and the underlying operating system state such as file descriptors and memory bounds (and perhaps some values from the standard C library such as `errno` for `libstdc++`, and signal handlers and timers for `libpthread`.

To avoid over-broad interpretation, I will add a remark:  at times there *can be sensible grounds* for wanting to statically link against even such basic libraries as `libstdc++` and even `libc`, and even though it is becoming a bit more difficult with recent systems and versions of those libraries (due to a bit of coupling with the loader and special linker tricks used), it is *definitely possible* - I did it a few times, and know of other cases in which it is still done.  *However*, in that case you need to link **a whole executable** statically.  Static linkage with standard libraries *combined with dynamic linkage* with other objects is not normally feasible.

---

*Edit*:  One issue which I forgot to mention but is important to take into account is C++ specific.  C++ was unfortunately not designed to work well with the classic model of object linkage and loading (used on Unix and other systems).  This makes shared libraries in C++ not really portable as they should be, because a lot of things such as type information and templates are not cleanly separated between objects (often being taken, together with a lot of actual library code at compile time from the headers).  `libstdc++` for that reason is tightly coupled with GCC, and code compiled with one version of `g++` will in general only work with the `libstdc++` from with this (or a very similar) version of `g++`.  As you will surely notice if you ever try to build a program with GCC 4 with any non-trivial library on your system that was built with GCC 3, this is not just `libstdc++`.  If your reason for wanting to do that is trying to ensure that your shared object is always linked with the specific versions of `libstdc++` and `libpthread` that it was built against, this would not help because a program that uses a different/incompatible `libstdc++` would also be built with an incompatible C++ compiler or version of `g++`, and would thus fail to link with your shared object anyway, *aside from the actual `libstdc++` conflicts*.

*If you wonder "why wasn't this done simpler?", a general rumination worth pondering*:  For C++ to work nicely with dynamic/shared libraries (meaning compatibility across compilers, and the ability to replace a dynamic library with another version with a compatible interface without rebuilding everything that uses it), not just compiler standartization is needed, but at the level of the operating system's loader, the structure and interface of object and library files and the work of the linker would need to be significantly extended beyond the relatively simple Unix classics used on common operating systems (*Microsoft Windows, Mach based systems and NeXTStep relatives such as Mac OS, VMS relatives and some mainframe systems also included*) *for natively built code* today.  The linker and dynamic loader would need to be aware of such things as templates and typing, **having to some extent functionality of a small compiler** to actually adapt the library's code to the type given to it - and (*personal subjective observation here*) it seems that higher-level intermediate intermediate code (together with higher-level languages and just-in-time compilation) is catching ground faster and likely to be standardized sooner than such extensions to the native object formats and linkers.

Comment: What I am trying to achievis to find out how to port c++ library to a embedded device. uClibc works fine. Still, I need stdc++ which is quite bulky and given that I use only a fraction of what's inside linking is statically may help. Any ideas?

Comment: Some simple ideas I put in a separate answer (I'm a StackOverflow newbie but thought that is the best way) might help you depending on your needs which may also be more complex.  You may get more elaborate answers for your case if you edit your question adding specific details at the end.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in a separate comment that you are trying to port a C++ library to an embedded device.  (*I am adding a new answer here instead of editing my original answer here because I think other StackOverflow users interested in this original question may still be interested in that answer in its context*)

- Obviously, depending on how stripped down your embedded system is (I have not much embedded Linux experience, so I am not sure what is most likely), you may of course be able to just install the shared `libstdc++` on it and dynamically link everything as you would do otherwise.
- If dynamically linking with `libstdc++` would not be good for you or not work on your system (there are so many different levels of embedded systems that one cannot know), and you need to link against a static `libstdc++`, then as I said, your only real option is static linking the executable using the library with it and `libstdc++`.  You mentioned porting a library to the embedded device, but if this is for the purpose of using it in some code you write or build on the device and you do not mind a static `libstdc++`, then linking everything statically (aside from perhaps `libc`) is probably OK.
- If the size of `libstdc++` is a problem, and you find that your library is actually only using a small part of its interfaces, then I would nonetheless suggest first trying to determine the actual space you would save by linking against only the parts you need.  It may be significant or not, I never looked that deep into `libstdc++` and I suspect that it has a lot of internal dependencies, so while you surely do not need some of the interfaces, you may or may not still depend on a big part of its internals - I do not know and did not try, but it may surprise you.  You can get an idea by just linking a binary using the library against a static build of it and `libstdc++` (not forgetting to strip the binary, of course), and comparing the size of the resulting executable that with the total size of a (`strip`ped) executable dynamically linked together with the full (`strip`ped) shared objects of the library and `libstdc++`.

  If you find that the size difference is significant, but do not want to statically link everything, you try to reduce the size of `libstdc++` by rebuilding it without some parts you know that you do not need (there are configure-time options for some parts of it, and you can also try to remove some independent objects at the final creation of `libstdc++.so`.  There are some tools to optimize the size of libraries - search the web (I recall one from a company named [MontaVista](http://www.mvista.com/) but do not see it on their web site now, there are some others too).

Other than the straightforward above, some ideas and suggestions to think of:

You mentioned that you use `uClibc`, which I never fiddled with myself (my experience with embedded programming is a lot more primitive, mostly involving assembly programming for the embedded processor and cross-compiling with minimal embedded libraries).  I assume you checked this, and I know that `uClibc` is intended to be a lightweight but rather full standard C library, but do not forget that C++ code is hardly independent on the C library, and `g++` and `libstdc++` depend on quite some delicate things (I remember problems with `libc` on some proprietary Unix versions), so I would not just assume that `g++` or the GNU `libstdc++` actually works with `uClibc` without trying - I don't recall seeing it mentioned in the `uClibc` pages.

Also, if this is an embedded system, think of its performance, compute power, overall complexity, and timing/simplicity/solidity requirements.  Take into consideration the complexity involved, and think whether using C++ and threads is appropriate in your embedded system, and if nothing else in the system uses those, whether it is worth introducing for that library.  It may be, not knowing the library or system I cannot tell (again, embedded systems being such a wide range nowadays).

And in this case also, just a quick link I stumbled upon looking for `uClibc` -- if you are working on an embedded system, using `uClibc`, and want to use C++ code on it -- take a look at `uClibc++`.  I do not know how much of the standard C++ stuff you need and it already supports, and it seems to be an ongoing project, so not clear if it is in a state good enough for you already, but assuming that your work is also under development still, it might be a good alternative to GCC's `libstdc++` for your embedded work.

Comment: Tom, thanks for extensive explanation. My original idea was to avoid installing libstdc++ on the device by linking with it statically (the library doesn't use exceptions and rtti). However, it looks like uClibc++ may be the way to go now.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this guy](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/) explains quite well why that wouldn't make sense. C++ code that uses your shared object but a different libstdc++ would link alright, but wouldn't work.